# запрос в sql update не работает winforms(c#)

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

У меня есть 4 столбца: Id, Name, Price, Amount. В UPDATE, при добавлении  количества товаров, но не изменяя цену, количество добавляется, а вот цена обнуляется.

Как можно сделать цену чтобы не обнулялось?

Код:

```
private void buttonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(textBoxIdUpdate.Text!="" &&
            ((textBoxPriceUpdate.Text!="" || textBoxAmountUpdate.Text!="") ||
                    (textBoxPriceUpdate.Text != "" && textBoxAmountUpdate.Text != "")))
    {
        string query = "UPDATE Store SET Amount=Amount+@amount, 
        Price=(case when IFNULL(@price,0)=0 then Price else @price end)  WHERE Id=@id";

        try{
            connection.Open();
            command = new SQLiteCommand(query, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textBoxIdUpdate.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", textBoxAmountUpdate.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", textBoxPriceUpdate.Text);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Успешно изменено");
            ShowGoods();
            textBoxIdUpdate.Text = "";
            textBoxPriceUpdate.Text = "";
            textBoxAmountUpdate.Text = "";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Заполните поля");
    }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73429/discussion-on-question-by-----sql-update---win).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно же, что проблема в строке:

```
case when IFNULL(@price,0)=0 then Price else @price end
```

т.е. в случае, если передаваемое значение `@price == null`, тогда берется существующее значение из базы, иначе берется передаваемое значение `@price`. Видимо в строке:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", textBoxPriceUpdate.Text);
```

туда все-таки что-то передается, возможно пустая строка.

```
"" != null - пустая строка - это не нуль, если что..
```

Вот и получается, что по условию у нас передается не нуль, а значит взять надо именно это значение - и берется пустая строка..

Comment: это понятно, не нашел решение как конвертировать строку в число.

Comment: я передаю ID и количество, а полю цена оставляю пустую, потом цена равно 0 становиться.

Comment: когда мне будет изменить цену, тогда что мне делать?

Comment: пробовал и так, щась в интернете поищу хорошенько, спасибо вам за ответ.

Comment: Ура, я нашел как решить проблему. int i; int? temp = int.TryParse(textBoxPriceUpdate.Text, out i) ? (int?)i : null;